# Simple application to populate an asp.net Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I can't seem to get my code to work.
It's a simple application to populate an asp.net GridView control.
The grid control is not getting populated and I am not getting an error message.
What am I missing here?

**Codebehind**

```
public void DisconnectedDataform()
{
    try
    {
        Initdata();

        gvProjectList.DataSource = dsProjectList;
        gvProjectList.DataMember = tableName;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Response.Write(e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    { }
}  

    public void Initdata()
    {
        try
        {
            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbProjectManager"].ConnectionString;

            dsProjectList = new DataSet();
            daProjectList = new SqlDataAdapter("select PersonID, FirstName, LastName from Person", conn);

            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(daProjectList);
            daProjectList.Fill(dsProjectList, "ProjectList");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Response.Write(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        { }
    }
```

**ASPX code:**

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvProjectList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataKeyNames="PersonID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PersonID" HeaderText="PersonID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PersonID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: after setting the datasource try gvProjectList.DataBind();

Comment: @Sam1 Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after setting the datasource try

```
gvProjectList.DataBind();
```